# Unable to draw legend at desired place in chart js

Tags: charts, chart.js

I want to draw the legend as shown in the image below.

[image]

But as per the chart js documentation, we cannot place legend in chart area at this position.

please provide any solution.

I am able to do this as shown in image below.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I leave you a small example of how it would be done.

```
plugins: {
    legend: {
        display: true,
        align: "start",
        position: 'right'
    }
},
```

**Complete code**

https://jsfiddle.net/SeiryuV/dxg4L3kw/70/

Comment: Hi,
Thanks for your response!
It can be done like how you told.
But I want that legend to be inside the chart area.
Can you please help on that?

Comment: Hi, the only way I can think of is to make your own legend.
I leave you a pretty good video where they explain how to do it.
[CustomLegend](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0OIZnoZ8GUU)

Comment: I will be waiting for any answer.